# Nothing appears when typing when using java scanner

Tags: java, input, keyboard, output, java.util.scanner

I have a very simple java script, where i have a scanner and want to type into the console. But nothing shows up on the console when I type in eclipse. I don't understand what's wrong.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("yo");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not take any input.

Try to wait an input first:

```
String nextInput = input.nextLine();
System.out.println(nextInput);
```

Comment: I could not understand correctly? You can inform user for write an input with adding System.out.println("write an input"); just before nextInput line.

Answer (score 0):

Well you should use:

`public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(input.next());
 }`

Now you will get what you will write in console